# Не работает простой javascript в Chrome на Android 4.2 / 4.3

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webbrowser, браузер

Есть форма (тест), содержащая несколько вопросов, на которые надо давать ответы путем выбора от 0 до 5 баллов. Сделано радиокнопками:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_0_1" id="answer_0_1_0" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="question_0_1" id="answer_0_1_1" value="1">
...
<input type="radio" name="question_0_1" id="answer_0_1_5" value="5">
```

Есть функция, которая пробегается по всем вопросам, дергает у каждого из них значение ответа и суммирует в переменную `scores`:

```
var temp = 0;
var scores = 0;

function doTest() {
  for (i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
    temp=document.getElementById('test_form')["question_"+i].value;
    if(temp !="") {scores+=parseInt(temp);}
    else {/* тут ругань валидатора */}
  }
}
```

На компьютере все нормально. На более-менее современном планшете тоже. А вот на смартфонах постарше (андроид 4.3, Chrome 28 и штатный браузер андроида 4.2 (юзер-агент: `Lenovo-A880/S100 Linux/3.4.5 Android/4.2 Release/08.07.2013 Browser/AppleWebkit 534.30 Profile/Configuration;`)) в `scores` складывается `NaN`. Примитивный дебаг показал, что в переменную `temp` в цикле отдается `undefined`.

Что за фокусы?

Comment: Это к Вам вопрос, что за фокусы обращение к методам объекта который в принципе не должен содержать доступных методов. Chrome 68  возвращает пустой список при вызове `getElementById`

Comment: Хм. эта форма имеет также имя. Обращение вида `document.myFormName['input_id'].value  приводит к тому же результату, сталбыть, что-то не так принципиально. Но как тогда правильно?

Comment: Обратился к элементам формы как `document.myFormName.elements['input_id'].value`. Подлечило в Хроме 28 под андроидом 4.3, но не сработало в штатном браузере андроида 4.2. Блин, что не так?...

Comment: К сожалению под рукой нет 4.2 попробуйте вывести в консоль что возвращает `document.myFormName.elements` это должен быть  объект `HTMLFormControlsCollection`

Comment: И если не секрет для чего вам поддержка столь устаревшего браузера? Даже на старых андроидах все в основном пользуются Chrome

Comment: под андроидом нет возможности вывести в консоль - отладка по USB не получается, устройство не детектится. попробовал вывести в отдельный дивчик, получил отаке: вывожу `document.myFormName.elements` - вижу `[object HTMLCollection]`, вывожу его же в виде `JSON.stringify(document.myFormName.elements)` - вижу пустое место. В современном браузере, да, выводит `HTMLFormControlsCollection`.

Comment: А поддержка старого браузера нужна потому что у половины целевой аудитории старенькие, но работающие смартфоны, на которые хром никто и не думал ставить никогда.  Юзер-агент моего браузера: `Lenovo-A880/S100 Linux/3.4.5 Android/4.2 Release/08.07.2013 Browser/AppleWebkit 534.30 Profile/Configuration;`

Comment: `[object HTMLCollection]` это не плохой знак, это итерируемый объект попробуйте вывести все его значения через `for..in`

Comment: выводит список объектов в виде номеров. Если в `for...in` выводить определенные свойства - выводит. В том числе и `name` сетов радиокнопок формы. Но вот если к тому же объекту  обратиться и попробовать получить элемент по вышеупомянутому `name` - выдает `object NodeList`, у которого нет `value`. Современный браузер возвращает же нормальный `object RadioNodeList`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема оказалась в том, что в старом браузере получение значения у набора радиокнопок, имеющих общее имя, по этому имени не работает: вместо нормального `RadioNodeList` старый браузер возвращает `NodeList`, у которого нет свойства `value`. Полифилл для этого дела решил проблему: https://gist.github.com/Raynos/1647489